# XSLT Transformation/Mapping Conversion Issue

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I need some help with XSLT conversion with XSLT 1.0 version. I have the following in the input XML:

```
<Top>
    <Test1>testLink1</Test1>
    <Test2>someHttpLink</Test2>
    <XYZ>
        <File>RelativePath/src/ext/config/abc.js</File>
        <File>RelativePath/src/ext/style/abcd.sass</File>
        <File>RelativePath/styles.sass</File>
        <File>test.log</File>
    </XYZ>
</Top>
```

I am trying to get the values in each  section and assign the values to properties like theFile.=
so, for the above input - the expected output I need is:

```
theFile.count=4 *(Since the count of the <File> tag in the above input xml is 4)*
theFile.1=RelativePath/src/ext/config/abc.js
theFile.2=RelativePath/src/ext/style/abcd.sass
theFile.3=RelativePath/styles.sass
theFile.4=test.log
```

Since, I am not very good at the XSLT conversion; I tried many things per my understanding like following -

```
<xsl:for-each select="File">
theFile.<xsl:value-of select="position()" />=<xsl:value-of select="../File"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="Top/XYZ">
theFileTryOne.count=<xsl:for-each select="Top/XYZ/File"><xsl:value-of select="position()"/><xsl:if test="position() != count(../File)" >,</xsl:if></xsl:for-each>
<xsl:for-each select="Top/XYZ/File">
theFileTryOne.<xsl:value-of select="position()" />=<xsl:value-of select="../File"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:if>

<xsl:if test="Top/XYZ">
theFileTryTwo.count=<xsl:for-each select="Top/XYZ/File"><xsl:value-of select="position()"/><xsl:if test="position() != count(../File)" >,</xsl:if></xsl:for-each>
<xsl:for-each select="Top/XYZ">
theFileTryTwo.<xsl:value-of select="position()" />=<xsl:value-of select="File"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:if>
```

but for these things I'm getting the following output:

```
theFile.count=1,2,3,4
theFile.1=RelativePath/src/ext/config/abc.js
theFile.2=RelativePath/src/ext/style/abcd.sass
theFile.3=RelativePath/styles.sass
theFile.4=test.log
theFileTryOne.count=1,2,3,4
theFileTryOne.1=RelativePath/src/ext/config/abc.js
theFileTryOne.2=RelativePath/src/ext/style/abcd.sass
theFileTryOne.3=RelativePath/styles.sass
theFileTryOne.4=test.log
theFileTryTwo.count=1,2,3,4
theFileTryTwo.1=RelativePath/src/ext/config/abc.js
```

I'm having trouble getting the expected output and need to know what would be the correct way to get the desired output.

Comment: Is there any way I can get the desired output with the existing input XML OR
By slightly modifying the input XML, can I get the desired output? If yes, how?

Comment: Could someone please help me with XSLT 1.0 version of the answer?

Comment: Why is this tagged as `xslt-grouping`?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I wasn't sure whether it categorizes into that, I now believe not; so removed the tag from question. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0 I would do something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/Top">
    <xsl:variable name="files" select="XYZ/File" />
    <xsl:text>theFile.count=</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="count($files)" />
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="$files">
        <xsl:text>theFile.</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
        <xsl:text>=</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

With XSLT 3.0 you can use e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="Top">
    <xsl:value-of select="'theFile.count=' || count(.//File), .//File!('theFile.' || position() || '=' || .)" separator="&#10;"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin for quick response, I just realized that we're using XSLT 1.0 version and that can't be changed (I updated my question to mention of XSLT 1.0 now). Can we achieve the same using XSLT 1.0?

If not possible with the existing input XML, Is it possible that by slightly modifying the input XML, can I get the desired output? If yes, how?

Comment: @Prashant2329, don't tag a question with XSLT 3 if you later reject an XSLT 3 answer. But spelling that out with XSLT 1 is possible, I will let others answer it then.

Comment: Yes Martin, you're absolutely right. I found that later and then immediately updated the question, but you're pretty quick :)

Could you please help me with the 1.0 please? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you please maybe directly update your answer for that and I'd accept your answer.

Comment: Could someone please help me with XSLT 1.0 version of the answer?

Comment: @Prashant2329 Please do not nag.